# Random vector between 0 and 1

Tags: octave

To generate a vector 1-20 I use :

```
a = [1:20]'
```

How to generate a vector of size 20 where each element is between 0-1 ?

Closest I've got is `a = [rand():rand()]'`

But how to generate a range ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the output you would like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
v = rand(20, 1)
```

You can then sort the vector:

```
s = sort(v)
```

Comment: Equivalent to `s=randperm(20)`?